# How to read Email

Tags: android

I have a question. I must create a program with a service in backgroud, to control inbox emails and if an email comes from a defined address I do something. Can you help me? I don't find any guide to read emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to query for it. That's fast and supported on every device: [ContactsContract](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.html) (There's even an example)